# Contact Key v/s Subscriber Key

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

What is the difference between the Contact key and the Subscriber key in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

I need to be clear on these so I can absolutely transfer this information. I have read the help material but I think I need it with an example as I still don't quite get it.

Comment: Have a look at the answer on this thread: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193008/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-contact-id-contact-key-subscriber-k

Answer (score 1):

**Contacts and Subscribers**

- A contact is a person you send messages to through any marketing
  channel. A contact typically appears in the All Contacts section, but
  a contact record can also appear in other locations.
- A subscriber is a person who opted to receive communications or
  belongs to a particular channel. A subscriber lives in the individual
  studios. Subscribers can be imported or created manually and are
  stored in data extensions.

Keep in mind that all subscribers are contacts, but not all contacts are subscribers. With email, a contact is somebody you sent emails to, so a subscriber in Email Studio will always be a contact. You can have contacts whom you’ve never sent to who don’t appear in All Contacts. For example, contact information imported into a sendable data extension but not included in a send doesn't appear in All Contacts. A subscriber is only added to All Contacts once something is sent to them. For instance, you might send the contact email and mobile messages, so the contact could be a mobile subscriber, and not an email subscriber.

**[Resources](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/understand-contacts-and-contact-model-relationships)**